# Dynamically save an assetbundle during run time

Tags: c#, unity

I'm wondering if it is possible to dynamically save / amend a current asset bundle during the running of my Unity application.

I've been looking into this for a few hours, but can't find anything about how to do this. I know you can download / stream assets from a server at run time, but I'm interesting in knowing if it's possible to do the same but in the opposite direction.

Has anyone ever attempted this before? Is there any good examples of how this could be done?

Comment: This, once again, would be of greater value in [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html). The question is good none-the-less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way to create assetbundle is to use BuildPipeline. BuildPipeline is an editor class, so it cannot be used in game.
However this does not prevent you from creating your own assets. For example you could create a png in run-time, upload it, then download it another time and use WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture to use the image as texture.